# Unable to run a command that contains single quotes through ssh

Tags: bash, awk, ssh

I can the following command on a machine (let's call it machine A).

```
find /foo/bar -name "*" -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort
```

This command lists the `md5`s of the files under `/foo/bar`.

However, when I append this command into an ssh command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key my_user@123.123.123.123 'find /foo/bar -name "*" -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort'
```

It generates the following error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

`123.123.123.123` is the IP address of machine A. The ssh command is run from another machine.

Is it possible to append the command into the ssh command?

I've tried the following command, it doesn't work, either.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key my_user@123.123.123.123 'find /foo/bar -name "*" -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk \'{print $1}\' | sort'
```

Comment: Could you please try to escape `$` in `awk` by doing `\$` in your code let us know then?

Comment: Using `\$` to replace `$` generates the same error message.

Comment: I think you need to escape the single quotes around the `awk` statement. Could you try?

Comment: I've tried, but haven't found a solution.

Comment: What about switching to double quote? Like `ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key my_user@123.123.123.123 "find /foo/bar -name \"*\" -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort"`

Comment: @Brian: How did you try to escape? Your edit seems wrong.

Comment: Your last attempt just needs to use `$'...'`, not `'...'` for the outermost quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The single quote after `awk` terminates the opening single quote before `find`.

In your case, there is no parameter expansion being done in your command. Hence the easiest would be to use double quotes for the ssh command.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key my_user@123.123.123.123 "find /foo/bar -name '*' -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort"
```

An alternative would be to replace each `'` around the `awk` argument by `'"'"'`, but this is awkward to read.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes cannot appear (even escaped) inside a single-quoted string. But they *can* appear (properly escaped) in an ANSI-quoted string.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_key my_user@123.123.123.123 \
 $'find /foo/bar -name "*" -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk \'{print $1}\' | sort'
```